# Parsing quarto documents

Tags: r-markdown, quarto

Consider the following `quarto` document:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
---

# My Section

This is the content of my section.

## Subsection 1

This is the content of my subsection 1.

## Subsection 2

This is the content of my subsection 2.
```

I need to parse the entire content of each section and subsection, using Python. One way is to use regex, but I am wondering whether there is a package for that likewise [`parsermd`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/parsermd/)in R.